# Remove alternator before cleaning

Tags: alternator

Removed alternator, sprayed brake cleaner inside and out.blew it out with air reinstalled it. works fine.   charging at 14.5 volts .dont know how long it will last?????  Do you?

Comment: Was there an issue with it to begin with? And, with a fix like this, it could last 20 minutes or 20 years, there's no telling.

Comment: Question certainly needs more detail, but I attempted an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing that cleaning an alternator could fix would be a stuck "brush".  A brush is a common part of an electric motor (or alternator) that wears down over time.  They normally have a spring that holds tension on them as they wear.  If the brushes were "stuck", the alternator would stop charging.  *If* this is what happened, it should keep working for a long time - until the brushes stick again or fail completely.

Of course since you removed and replaced it, the problem could have just been a bad connection.

Motor bushes with springs:
[image]